# Outlook default Sort type copy into every folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sorting

So I was just given a company email in Outlook 365 that has close to 100 folder. Somehow Outlook has chosen to sort every one of them by **Subject**

Is there any way to choose a default sort type into Outlook that copies it to every mail folder you have under it?

I would like to change the sorting into **Date**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Windows Key + R to bring up the run command window.

Type

```
outlook.exe /CleanViews
```

and press enter. This should start outlook with all the views reset to default (sorted by date).

Comment: Thank you this fixed the problem! :)